# Typescript 2.3 not compiling AMD correctly in Visual Studio?

Tags: typescript, requirejs, amd

So, I am having issues with the compilation of converted C# classes using Typewriter. The typescript produced which I will show below doesn't properly compile to requiring dependencies in JS output. This results in a bunch of missing files in the browser.

Here is an example of the typescript with an import statement from another file - the other file looks very similar to this code with an exported Interface and Class:

If you can help me understand what is happening here it would be greatly appreciated.

```
// -- Imports --
import { ChecklistItemState, IChecklistItemState } from './ChecklistItemState';
//

// -- Interface --
export interface IChecklistItem {

    itemId: number;
    workflowPhaseId: number;
    task: string;
    description: string;
    sortOrder: number;
    created: Date;
    modified: Date;
    state: ChecklistItemState;
}
//

// -- Knockout Class --
export class ChecklistItem {        

    itemId = ko.observable<number>();
    workflowPhaseId = ko.observable<number>();
    task = ko.observable<string>();
    description = ko.observable<string>();
    sortOrder = ko.observable<number>();
    created = ko.observable<Date>();
    modified = ko.observable<Date>();
    state = ko.observable<ChecklistItemState>();

    constructor(model: IChecklistItem) {
        this.map(model);
    }
    //

    //  -- Map Interface to Class --
    map(model: IChecklistItem) {

        this.itemId(model.itemId);
        this.workflowPhaseId(model.workflowPhaseId);
        this.task(model.task);
        this.description(model.description);
        this.sortOrder(model.sortOrder);
        this.created(model.created);
        this.modified(model.modified);
        this.state(model.state);

    }
    //



    // -- Return JSON Model --
    getModel() {
        return {

            itemId: this.itemId(),
            workflowPhaseId: this.workflowPhaseId(),
            task: this.task(),
            description: this.description(),
            sortOrder: this.sortOrder(),
            created: this.created(),
            modified: this.modified(),
            state: this.state(),

        }
    }
    //
}
//
```

You can see that ChecklistItemState is being used not only in the Interface of IChecklistItem but also the class of ChecklistItem as 'state'.

You would imagine that the compilation of this code would be a require statement for the ./ChecklistItemState file but here is the actual compiled code:

```
  define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    //
    // -- Knockout Class --
    var ChecklistItem = (function () {
        function ChecklistItem(model) {
            this.itemId = ko.observable();
            this.workflowPhaseId = ko.observable();
            this.task = ko.observable();
            this.description = ko.observable();
            this.sortOrder = ko.observable();
            this.created = ko.observable();
            this.modified = ko.observable();
            this.state = ko.observable();
            this.map(model);
        }
        //
        //  -- Map Interface to Class --
        ChecklistItem.prototype.map = function (model) {
            this.itemId(model.itemId);
            this.workflowPhaseId(model.workflowPhaseId);
            this.task(model.task);
            this.description(model.description);
            this.sortOrder(model.sortOrder);
            this.created(model.created);
            this.modified(model.modified);
            this.state(model.state);
        };
        //
        // -- Return JSON Model --
        ChecklistItem.prototype.getModel = function () {
            return {
                itemId: this.itemId(),
                workflowPhaseId: this.workflowPhaseId(),
                task: this.task(),
                description: this.description(),
                sortOrder: this.sortOrder(),
                created: this.created(),
                modified: this.modified(),
                state: this.state(),
            };
        };
        return ChecklistItem;
    }());
    exports.ChecklistItem = ChecklistItem;
});
//
//# sourceMappingURL=ChecklistItem.js.map
```

To show that it compiles other code correctly here is another snippet of code that shows the "define" call in the compiled JS correctly.

```
import { SnakeViewModel } from '../../../Core/classes/SnakeViewModel';

let initModel = {
    projId: $("#projId").val(),
    wfId: $("#wfId").val()
},
viewModel;
$.post("/ProjectApi/ProjectSnakeView",
initModel,
data => {
    if (data != null) {
        console.log(data);
        var viewModel = new SnakeViewModel(data);
    }
});
```

And then here is the compiled output of that code:

```
define(["require", "exports", "../../../Core/classes/SnakeViewModel"], 
function (require, exports, SnakeViewModel_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var initModel = {
        projId: $("#projId").val(),
        wfId: $("#wfId").val()
    }, viewModel;
    $.post("/ProjectApi/ProjectSnakeView", initModel, function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            console.log(data);
            var viewModel = new SnakeViewModel_1.SnakeViewModel(data);
        }
    });
});
//# sourceMappingURL=snake.js.map
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of the compilation look fine to me.

What's happening is that the TypeScript compiler will emit a dependency in the compiled code for modules that you import **if and only if your code depends on them at run-time.** If your code depends on them only for type-checking, then that is a compile-time dependency and the compiler won't emit a dependency in the compiled code.

In your first TypeScript snippet, you depend on `./ChecklistItemState` only at compile-time, in order to perform type checks, and not at run-time and thus you don't get a dependency for it. (If you added a statement like `new ChecklistItemState` or `x instanceof ChecklistItemState`, then you'd have a run-time depenency and would get a dependency emitted in the compiled code.)

In your 2nd TypeScript snippet, you use `new SnakeViewModel`. So your code needs to be able to find the `SnakeViewModel` function at run-time, and thus a run-time dependency is needed for your code to run.

Comment: Ok, that straitens out my understanding of that. So now I need to figure out why `var viewModel = new SnakeViewModel(data);` is coming back undefined.. SnakeViewModel resembles the ChecklistItem class structure just much more complex. Any ideas on next steps?

Comment: If `viewModel` remains undefined, that's a different problem from the one you focused on when you wrote your question. You're dealing with asynchronous code there. Are you sure you are looking at `viewModel` correctly?  Did you try putting a `console.log` **immediately** after `var viewModel = new SnakeViewModel(data);` and see what value `viewModel` has? It is important that the `console.log` be **immediately** after the `new` call, and not, for instance, at the end of your module. (I also see you are defining `viewModel` twice: in the outer scope of the module and in the callback.)

Comment: Turns out it was a matter of Title vs Camel - ugh... Now i'm realizing my KO observable is only one level deep... Here we go on the journey of traversing and instantiation each of the lower level objects from SnakeViewModel :). Thanks for getting me out of the weeds in my own mind lol.